# Python Fizzbuzz problems with loop

Tags: python, loops, fizzbuzz

I've searched for the answer for about an hour, and it seems most people have coded fizzbuzz a different way than myself.

However, having tried everything to figure out why this simple code will not work I'm getting extremely frustrated.

Can anyone point out the simple problem I'm sure I'm having? The code runs but it just returns the value 1.

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):
    for n in intList:
        if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
            return n.replace(str(n),"Fizzbuzz")
        elif n % 3 == 0:
            return n.replace(str(n),"Fizz")
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            return n.replace(str(n),"Buzz")
        else:
            return n
```

Comment: And i apologize, my for loop and if/else statements ARE indented properly, i messed up when pasting.  (obviously im new here lol)

Answer (score 1):

The first value it looks at is `1`. Since `1%x` is only `0` for an `x` of `1`, it goes to the `else` and returns `1`. And then it's done, because that's what `return` does.

That leads to the bigger problem, which is that you are starting a loop and then guaranteeing that you will leave that loop after only one iteration, because there's a `return` in every branch. You'll need to replace those `return` statements with either `append()`s to a `list` (don't forget to `return` the resulting `list`) or `print()` calls.

Also, if you started with something like `3`, your code would try to use `replace` on an integer, which is not something you can do with integers. You would get a traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The code is returning `1` because consider this list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. All three conditions will get `false` and the last `else` will return `1`. If you want the answer, append them into list.

Something like this:

```
def fizzbuzz(intList):
    temp = []
    for n in intList:
        if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
            temp.append("Fizzbuzz")
        elif n % 3 == 0:
            temp.append("Fizz")
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            temp.append("Buzz")
        else:
            temp.append(n)
    return temp


print fizzbuzz(range(1,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you take a look at this code you will
better understand yours. Although this is a completely
different implementation of fizzbuzz in Python3

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

for i in range(1,100):
    msg = "Fizz" * bool(i%3==0)
    msg += "Buzz" * bool(i%5==0)
    if not msg:
        msg = i
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

My skills in python are fairly average but i love using dicitonaries. Here is the Fizz Buzz  program using dictionaries.Without an if.

```
for data in range(1, 101):
    msg = [str((data % 3 == 0)), str((data % 5 == 0))]
    // msg returns a list with ['True' ,'False'] depending on the condition
    conveter = {"True False": "Fizz",
                "False True": "Buzz",
                "True True": "Fizz Buzz",
                "False False": data
            }
    val = conveter[" ".join(msg)]
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented FizzBuzz as

```
for n in range(1, 100):
    if n%15==0: print "FizzBuzz"
    elif n%5==0: print "Buzz"
    elif n%3==0: print "Fizz"
    else: print n
```

The best thing with it that

- It works
- It fits into a tweet, with a margin

Answer (score 0):

Years later, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103081/1327325)...

> FizzBuzz: For integers up to and including 100, prints FizzBuzz if the integer is divisible by 3 and 5 (15); Fizz if it's divisible by 3 (and not 5); Buzz if it's divisible by 5 (and not 3); and the integer otherwise.

```
def FizzBuzz():
    for i in range(1,101):
        print {
            3 : "Fizz",
            5 : "Buzz",
            15 : "FizzBuzz"}.get(15*(not i%15) or
                                 5*(not i%5 ) or
                                 3*(not i%3 ), '{}'.format(i))
```

The `.get()` method works wonders here.

Operates as follows

For all integers from 1 to 100 (101 is NOT included),
print the value of the dictionary key that we call via get according to these rules.

"Get the first non-False item in the `get` call, or return the integer as a string."

When checking for a `True` value, thus a value we can lookup, Python evaluates 0 to `False`. If i mod 15 = 0, that's False, we would go to the next one.

Therefore we `NOT` each of the 'mods' (aka remainder), so that if the mod == 0, which == False, we get a True statement. We multiply `True` by the dictionary key which returns the dictionary key (i.e. `3*True == 3`)

When the integer it not divisible by 3, 5 or 15, then we fall to the default clause of printing the int `'{}'.format(i)` just inserts i into that string - as a string.

Some of the output

Fizz
79
Buzz
Fizz
82
83
Fizz
Buzz
86
Fizz
88
89
FizzBuzz
91
92
Fizz
94
Buzz
Fizz
97
98
Fizz
Buzz

Answer (score 0):

how a python function should look like if we want to see the next result in the interactive mode of the python interpreter:

```
>>> fizz(15)
[ 1, 2, 'fizz', 4, 'buzz', 'fizz', 7, 8, 'fizz', 'buzz', 11, 'fizz', 13, 14, 'fizzbuzz' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input()) 
out = []
for i in range(1, n):
   if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0: 
     out.append("fizzbuzz") 
     continue 
   elif i % 3 == 0: 
     out.append("fizz") 
     continue 
   elif i % 5 == 0: 
     out.append("buzz")
     continue 
   out.append(i) 
 print(out)
```

Answer as [1,2,'fizz']

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input('Enter the number: '))
if x % 3 ==0 and x % 5 ==0:
    print('FizzBuzz')
elif x % 3 ==0:
    print('Fizz')
elif x % 5 ==0:
    print('Buzz')
else:
    print(f'{x} ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
```